# Transformation of Ito diffusion such that the diffusion coefficient becomes constant (Change of variables)

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I encountered a transformation of an Ito diffusion which yielded a new Ito diffusion such that the new diffusion coefficient was equal to $1$.

My question is whether there is something more general behind it and, if yes, whether it can be found anywhere in a book.

EDIT: I found that this is the so-called Lamperti-Transform, see e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiO9rXMnayAAxW1UKQEHd1rC9AQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Frepository.tudelft.nl%2Fislandora%2Fobject%2Fuuid%3A948769c8-49e5-4175-9990-76b3235f7a25%2Fdatastream%2FOBJ%2Fdownload&usg=AOvVaw16RQTrhvtTMMKhgO7UaOlM&opi=89978449)

Let me present you the transformation:

Let $\mu : \Bbb R \times [0,\infty ) \to \Bbb R$ and $\sigma : \Bbb R \times [0,\infty ) \to \Bbb R$ be smooth and bounded functions. Let $ (X_t )_{t\geq 0} $ be the solution to

$$ dX_t = \mu (X_t  , t ) dt + \sigma (X_t ,t) dB_t $$

where $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion.

Assume that
$$\inf_{(x,t) \in \Bbb R \times [0,\infty)} \sigma (x,t) > 0.$$

Define the function

$$f(x,t) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sigma (z,t) } dz $$
We have that $f \in C^{2,1}$ and for fixed $t$ the function $x\mapsto f(x,t)$ is strictly increasing, such that there exists a function $g : \Bbb R \times [0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ with
$$ f(g(y,t),t) = y$$
Using the Ito formula for the process $Y_t := f(X_t,t)$ we obtain that

$$ dY_t = \left[ \frac{\mu (X_t ,t)}{\sigma (X_t , t)} - \int_0^{X_t} \frac{\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial t} (z, t)}{\sigma (z,t)^2}dz - \frac 1 2 \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x} (X_t , t)\right] dt + dB_t\\
= \tilde \mu (Y_t , t) dt + dB_t, $$

where

$$\tilde \mu (y,t) := \frac{\mu (g(y,t) ,t)}{\sigma (g(y,t) , t)} - \int_0^{g(y,t)} \frac{ \frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial t} (z,t)}{\sigma (z,t)^2 }dz - \frac 1 2 \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x} (g(y,t) , t) .$$

Therefore, $(Y_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a Ito diffusion with diffusion coefficient equal to $1$.

- My question for a possible more general situation is concerned with the condition $\sigma \geq \varepsilon >0$. Maybe it is possible to generalize it to the situation that $\sigma^2 > 0$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ is locally integrable.
- A different way of transforming the diffusion coefficient is the method of random time change. Is there any relationship to the deterministic transformation with $f$?

Answer (score 1):

For Q1, in the references I found for Lamperti

- [The Lamperti Transform](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid%3A948769c8-49e5-4175-9990-76b3235f7a25)
- Schilling in "21.4 Transforming an SDE into a linear SD"
- Shreve-Karatzas 5.2 exercise 2.20

they all work with $\sigma^{2}>0$ (continuously differentiable).

For Q2, well the Lampert is about turning the volatility into $1$ (even if the drift is nonzero), whereas the time-change method requires zero drift as 5.5.A in Shreve-Karatzas or Dubins-Schwartz is about obtaining a time-changed Brownian motion, so they are quite different.